# How do I compact a file geodatabase with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, fme-form, file-geodatabase

I am preparing some data using FME, which I end up writing to an Esri file geodatabase. Unfortunately, FME doesn't appear to update the written feature classes' spatial indices. This results in display problems when I later inspect the written data with ArcMap (or other ArcGIS desktop tools).

It appears that there are two seemingly easy solutions for this problem:

- Recreate any spatial indices after writing data.
- Compact the file geodatabase after writing data.

Compacting seems like the easier choice, because it can be done per geodatabase (vs. recreating indices per feature class).

I don't want to compact the geodatabase manually; ideally I'd want to compact the geodatabase inside my FME workbench, using a shutdown Python script. However, there appears to be no ArcGIS geoprocessing tool for compacting a geodatabase (only one for compressing, which is not the same thing).

Does anyone have a solution here?

- Updating the spatial indices directly in FME; or
- compacting a file geodatabase using ArcPy (in an FME shutdown script).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a GeoProcessing tool called [Compact](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/compact.htm) that will compact file or personal geodatabases and can be used within a model or called by an arcpy script.

Comment: I must have gone blind. Or I can blame Esri for translating tool names in localized versions of ArcGIS. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The Help file is huge and ESRI seem to reconfigure it with each major release, it some times feels like the situation of you cannot see the wood for the trees!

Comment: Turns out there is also an option in the FME Geodatabase writer, the "advanced" area, which does Compact. Sadly, it is labeled "compress" and we know we need to fix that. But in an FME world, that is how you can get Compaction to happen.